# How to know which item is completely visible or focused in a FlatList?

Tags: android, react-native, focus, react-native-flatlist

My scenario is, I have a bunch of cards which are all rendered using `FlatList`. The card almost fills the screen width and we can see a small portion of the previous and next card. Is there any way to know which item is currently visible or focused in a FlatList so that I can add some highlight or blur the other items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use onViewableItemsChanged property of Flatlist for that .

Example ::

```
    onViewableItemsChanged = ({ viewableItem, changed }) => {
    console.log("Visible item", viewableItems);
    console.log("iteration", changed);
  }

<FlatList
onViewableItemsChanged={onViewableItemsChanged }
viewabilityConfig={{
itemVisiblePercentThreshold: 50
}}
      />
```